# Unable to start a ipython wrapper kernel in background through python

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

We have a requirement of starting the ipython kernel in the background through our backend server code. The kernel launches successfully but blocks the execution of the main thread.

Our Kernel code looks somewhat like this

```
from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel

class EchoKernel(Kernel):
    implementation = 'Echo'
    implementation_version = '1.0'
    language = 'no-op'
    language_version = '0.1'
    language_info = {'mimetype': 'text/plain'}
    banner = "Echo kernel - as useful as a parrot"

    def do_execute(self, code, silent, store_history=True, user_expressions=None,
                   allow_stdin=False):
        if not silent:
            stream_content = {'name': 'stdout', 'text': code}
            self.send_response(self.iopub_socket, 'stream', stream_content)

        return {'status': 'ok',
                # The base class increments the execution count
                'execution_count': self.execution_count,
                'payload': [],
                'user_expressions': {},
               }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
    IPKernelApp.launch_instance(kernel_class=EchoKernel)
```

The above code can be found in https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/wrapperkernels.html

We are tried to call the above program using  following api's

os.system() , os.popen() and subprocess.call()

The command would be "nohup python LaunchKernel.py >> output.txt &"

As this is a kernel program, would it be possible to launch in background? Any help in solving this would be of great help.